# setting a stopwatch timer after countdown timer has ended

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer, stopwatch

I have a countdown timer in my program, and I want to start a stopwatch timer that tracks every second, minute and hour that has elapsed after the countdown has finished. It should also continuously count, even if the user isn't on the website. It can only be stopped after the user has clicked a button.

```
  var countDownDate = new Date().getTime();

  var x = setInterval(function(){
    var currentDate = new Date().getTime();

    var distance = countDownDate - currentDate;

    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);


    if(days == 0 && hours == 0){
      document.getElementById("due").innerHTML = "due date";
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    }else if(hours == 0){
      document.getElementById("due").innerHTML = "due date";
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hours + "h" + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    }

    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      document.getElementById("due").innerHTML = "overdue by";
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The timer has run out";
    }

  },1000);
```

After the countdown, a stopwatch should start automatically. This stopwatch should continuously keep track of every second that passes, even if not on the website - unless it is stopped.

Comment: "it is also continuously counting even if the user isn't in the website", what do you exactlymean?

Comment: every time i see someone use setInterval for visible counters, it sends shivers down my spine even though i agree that this is the "quickest" solution

Comment: even when he goes to another part of the website the stopwatch is still counting the time that passes @Ferus7

Comment: @JasfferPadigdig so, what you need is to share the stopwatch between your pages,  I normally use redux for this cases, but there are mutiple ways to achieve this